# what means Access is denied?

Tags: c++

i have following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int n)
{
    int m=0;
    while (n>0)
    {
        m*=10;
        m+=n%10;
        n/=10;
    }
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    int n=97;
    cout<<reverse(n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when i run this code program says access is denied why?

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/mSZ4GQfN How are you running the program?

Comment: @st0le sounds like a Windows error message

Comment: You should avoid `using namespace std;`. `reserve` is already a function in the `std` namespace and having both your function and potentially the `std` version included in the same namespace has the potential to cause ambiguity in both the code and any generated error messages.

Comment: Typo: I meant `reverse`, not `reserve`, obviously!

Comment: chmod +x <output_file> on *nix systems, should work out of the box on Windows.

Comment: I -1'ed this, like I do with any post that has this horrible formatting

Comment: Fixed indenting (thanks astyle), it was unbearable to watch.

Answer (score 2):

There are no issues with the code you have posted, so the error may lie in the compiler, OS, or elsewhere in your code if what you have shown is not your entire project (which I doubt).

By the looks of it, you are just doing something horribly wrong.

Oh, and I wouldn't suggest changing the parameters to a function, make a temp value instead:

```
int reverse(int _n) {
  int n = _n;
  int m = 0;
  while(n>0) {
    m*=10;
    m+=n%10;
    n/=10;
  }
  return m;
}
```

And you should learn to properly indent your code, for readability sake. Unindented code is as attractive as men in dresses.

Comment: `+1` from me for the sentence about indentation. That code hurt my eyes.

Comment: +1 for "indent your code properly," -1 for "make a redundant variable."

Comment: I don't like modifying parameters, it seems improper for some reason.

Comment: It's not modifying the parameter, it's modifying a fresh copy of that parameter, since it's passed by value. Nothing wrong with that, the caller of the function won't notice.